# margin fixes list-style wordpress pages bullet points issue - how to stop them appearing in my main menu?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i added this to Wordpress so it would show bullet points (which seem to be hidden by my theme)

```
ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

it worked, but now the main navigation menu also had bullet points on each item and sub item.

i tried this to fix it, but it didnt work.

```
#menu ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Any ideas would be really appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**if you want to stop `list-style` add `none` infront of it.**

**removed list-style in menu links**

```
header .menu {
float: right;
position: relative;
z-index: 1000;
font-family: 'TitilliumText25L600wt';
list-style: none;
}
```

**removed list-style in sub links**

```
header .menu ul li ul li {
background-color: #ffb400;
background-image: none;
list-style: none;
}
```

**added border in sub links**

```
header .menu ul li:hover ul li a {
color: #ffffff;
background: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #5C5A52;
}
```

**Working screenshot**

[image]

Refer this link for more info

**http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/list-style/**

Comment: thanks for the reply. i came upon that answer earlier but it doesnt seem to work. the menu and some widgets still have bullet points where before they didnt.

here's the site: www.focallocal.og/ and a page with bullet points: http://focallocal.org/focallocal-kindness-auction/

also i have a numerical list on that page which wont show.. maybe its the theme?

Comment: that's brilliant, thanks very much. its fixed the header, but i still havent been able to take them away from widgets - without losing them in text written in pages and articles as well.

Comment: hmm...can you tell me which places you have ?? i mean if you provide me the links, i can fix it??

Comment: thank you! the bullet points are appearing on the sidebar widgets here: www.focallocal.org 

they dont look too bad, but shouldnt be there

Comment: you have a class called li in css edit this css **li {
list-style-type: none;
}** it will definately fix it

Comment: if there were a way to set different CSS rles for the homepage that would be very useful, but i cant find it via google

Answer (score 0):

Add to:
header .menu ul li (style.css line 343).

```
list-style: none;
```